# Numpy - Efficiently combine elements of array with regular intervals of another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to take 2 arrays, with one being double the size of the other, say:

```
a = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0] # The decimals are just to distinguish the 2 array's values
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

and combine them such that every n-th element of the "combined" array, *c*, contains the n-th element of *a*, as well as the (2n)-th and (2n + 1)-th elements of *b*

In this case we would have:

```
c = [[1.0,1,2], [2.0,3,4], [3.0,5,6], ... [6.0,11,12]]
```

I have a naive solution, but I need this to be done *extremely quickly* -- I'm working with million-long arrays and need the operation done as quickly as possible

What would be the best way to go about this? Numpy always seems to have a secret method to do stuff like this

Comment: Yes, I can -- my current solution is to take t = np.split(b, 2) and then do np.row_stack(a, t) -- it works, its just still too slow

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use Numpy for your requirement? Here there is a solution using only Python.

```
c = []    
for index, item in enumerate(a):
      c.append([a[index], b[2*index], b[2*index+1]])
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 1, 2], [2.0, 3, 4], [3.0, 5, 6], [4.0, 7, 8], [5.0, 9, 10], [6.0, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

a = a.reshape((-1, 1))
b = b.reshape((-1, 2))

# a is now like
# [[1.0],
#  [2.0],
#   ...
# ]
#
# b is like
#  [[1, 2],
#   [3, 4],
#   ...
#  ]

c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
# [[1.0, 1, 2],
#  [2.0, 3, 4],
#  ...
# ]
```

Note that of course `c` will have only one datatype, so it will be all floats rather than floats and ints.

EDIT: So the question has now been updated since `a` and `b` are in fact two dimensional. The inputs and outputs have been added as a comment to this question.

```
a = [[0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]]
b = [[0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0]]

# c = [[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0]], [[0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0]]...]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

number_groups = len(a)

a = a.reshape((n_groups, 1, -1))
b = b.reshape((n_groups, 2, -1))

c = np.concatenate((ar, br), axis=1)
```

Output is:

```
array([[[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]]])
```

Comment: thanks -- each of my elements of a and b are actually np arrays themselves of some (equal but unknown) size, is there a standard way to be able to reshape them similarly?

Comment: Okay, so `a` and `b` are two dimensional? The solution is very similar, just a change of reshaping and which axis to concatenate along. If you stick some example input arrays in your question I'll extend my answer to address that.

Comment: alright -- 

So a = [[0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1], ...] and b = [[0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], ...]

c = [[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0]], ...]

Comment: If you can add them to your question with an edit, rather than a comment here then that would be great for others finding the question. And add the expected output too.

Comment: Turns out this solution is actually really slow compared to what I had already :/

Comment: Updated my answer with the 2D inputs. Can you give me an idea of what speed you're getting and what your target is?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will be any more efficient but here's one way it could be done with list comprehension.

```py
c = [[x]+(b[idx*2:(idx*2)+2]) for idx, x in enumerate(a)]
```